# Classic ASP - Connect to database from external server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, asp-classic, external, ip-address

We are currently looking to migrate servers, however we need to for the time being allow the live website **to use the external database on the new server**.

Currently the string used to connect to the local server looks like this:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Password=Rave123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Usr123;Initial Catalog=sqldb12;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS
```

However I need to amend this to use an **IP Address to direct it to use the external server**.

I've attempted a number of different solutions but none work, please can you advise me on how to do this based on the system.

*The system is IIS 7 and it's a Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server Express Edition.*

Please use my details as above for the example query so it makes sense to me :)

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you should just add `Data Source=<server_ip>"` to your connection string.

Comment: Sorry Lawrence, I pasted the wrong connection line, please see the details updated on the post.

Provider=SQLNCLI10;Password=Rave123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Usr123;Initial Catalog=sqldb12;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: When pasting such data, you should change your username and password, this way you are creating a security issue. Just use `Password=<my_pass>` and everyone will know what it is. Also, I am not sure how this connection string is different in regards to my previous comment.

Comment: @Lawrence - you should post that as an answer.  There's a very useful website with a very easy to remember URL - www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connection string should be:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Password=Rave123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Usr123;Initial Catalog=sqldb12;Data Source=<IP address>
```

Or if it is a named instance:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Password=Rave123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Usr123;Initial Catalog=sqldb12;Data Source=<IP address>\<instance name>;
```

So if it is SQLExpress as a named instance:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Password=Rave123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Usr123;Initial Catalog=sqldb12;Data Source=<IP address>\SQLExpress
```

Comment: @ShaunS: if this works for you, accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: With regards to the provider within the statement... would this be the provider of the machine that is going to output the data or the one which hosts the information (the external server)??

Comment: @ShaunS It's the provider you are using to connect to the external server. You have to have the correct provider on your machine and the external server has to understand how to receive communication request from the provider.